# ERROR: Error installing jquery-rails: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3. in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, activesupport

I'm trying to install the latest ruby and latest rails in latest gem version

I have rvm  installed and created a new gemset named hotel

```
~$ rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247@hotel 
Using /home/circar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247 with gemset hotel

~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.0)
actionpack (4.0.0)
activemodel (4.0.0)
activerecord (4.0.0)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activesupport (4.0.0)
arel (4.0.0)
atomic (1.1.14)
builder (3.1.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
coffee-rails (4.0.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.0.1)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.5)
jbuilder (1.5.1)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.8.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0)
railties (4.0.0)
rake (10.1.0)
rubygems-update (2.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sprockets (2.10.0)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.37)

~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]
~$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0
~$ gem -v
2.1.1
```

But when  I'm trying to install

> jquery-rails

as

```
~$ sudo gem install jquery-rails
```

**It shows Error as**

```
ERROR:  Error installing jquery-rails:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

Anyone please help me to install the jquery-rails gem with the latest update environment.

The gem is also pointing the current rvm

```
$ which gem
/home/circar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem
```

I googled it, but i dont know why i stumble in  this place? I am unable to find any problem in my process, as stated everywhere.

Any help highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo gem install jquery-rails` is probably using your system's built-in Ruby (which is likely 1.8, or 1.9.2). This is because you're using `sudo`.

With RVM, get rid of the sudo and it'll use RVM instead:

```
gem install jquery-rails
```

Comment: My system gem version is currently updated to 2.1.1.
Moreover, the cmd 
gem install jquery-rails
 is also showing the same error

Comment: RubyGems version is different than Ruby version (there is no Ruby 2.1.1). It might be the `gem` is not using RVM's ruby either (`which gem` might be pointing to /usr/bin/gem instead of using RVM)